# cURL Post HTTP dont' work correctly by sending to Django site

Tags: php, curl

everybody

I need to send some form data to another url, when I try to send buy html it works correct, but when I use cURL I receive the following message "MultiValueDictKeyError"

What is from with this curl request?

```
&url = http://someurl.com;
$user = 'info@some.email';
$scenario_id = 100;
$order_id = rand(0, 999999999999);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query('user=$user&scenario_id=$scenario_id&order_id=$order_id'));     
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://someurl.com';
```

instead of:

```
&url = http://someurl.com;
```

Also:
http_build_query expects an array or object, not a string.

Comment: I have changed it before, it doesn't work.

Comment: So what code are you now using and what is the error?

Comment: The code works fine with PHP servers, but I receive "MultiValueDictKeyError" on Django website on "scenario_id" value

Comment: I edited the above answer.